# Spring boot. Kafka. Disconnect from Node

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'm getting disconnected from a Node when trying to **listen** to the subscribed topic. I do not need produce messages, it is already implemented. VPN is used to connect to Kafka.
I use Spring boot 2.7.0, Java 17.

**Configuration:**

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Configuration class:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "10.36.12.5:2181");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group-id");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>
            factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
}
```

Listener:

```
@Component
public class KafkaListenersService {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "ift.notification.clientId.request", groupId = "group-id")
    public void listen(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received Message in group - group-id: " + message);
    }

}
```

**What steps I have already done:**

1. I added host domain and its IP address to /etc/hosts. So it is being resolved correctly.
2. I used Offset Explorer 2 as a kafka tool and managed to connect to the specified host. I found the topic I needed and managed to read messages from it. I think it means that I am able to locally connect to kafka, so it means I can do it **from Java too**.
3. I also tried to move my settings for Kafka from @Configuration class to application.yml. It looked like this:

> ```
> spring:
>   kafka:
>     consumer:
>       bootstrap-servers: 10.36.12.5:2181
>       key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
>       value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
> ```

Alas I got disconnected and failed to read any messages as well.

**What I get in the logs:**

```
2022-11-22 20:29:21.715  INFO 5005 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.2.3
2022-11-22 20:29:21.716  INFO 5005 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 50029d3ed8ba576f
2022-11-22 20:29:21.716  INFO 5005 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1669134561713
2022-11-22 20:29:21.719  INFO 5005 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group-id-1, groupId=group-id] Subscribed to topic(s): ift.notification.clientId.request
2022-11-22 20:29:21.743  INFO 5005 --- [           main] insure.pulse.Main                        : Started Main in 2.153 seconds (JVM running for 2.83)
2022-11-22 20:29:22.265  INFO 5005 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group-id-1, groupId=group-id] Node -1 disconnected.
2022-11-22 20:29:22.268  INFO 5005 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group-id-1, groupId=group-id] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 1 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 149ms, elapsed time since send: 149ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2022-11-22 20:29:22.268  WARN 5005 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group-id-1, groupId=group-id] Bootstrap broker 10.36.12.5:2181 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

After that the Warning keeps repeating. I think it's because KafkaListener keeps trying to connect to Node.

Any help will be much appreciated. Feel free to ask for any additional info too, I will gladly provide it.

Comment: Are you sure kafka node is up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out what the reason was. I used connection to kafka via Offset Explorer 2 as a reference. I saw that Zookeeper port was **2181**:
[image] so I used it as a port for bootstrap-server in my application.yml as well:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: 10.36.12.5:2181
```

That was my mistake. It seems that zookeeper is not a bootstrap-server, but it kind of gives you the address to a bootstrap-server. So the address of the bootstrap server itself (and its specific port) should be specified in the application.yml:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: 10.36.12.5:9092
```

I found the bootstrap-server port in Offset Explorer as well:

[image]

When I fixed it everything worked fine.

Comment: `9092` is the port without authentication, right?